# Joomla - error 500 in administrator

Tags: joomla

A new error on my website occured. I think I did not make any changes that could cause this problem.

I can login in admin normally and then when I click on everything except installed components there is 500 server error.

Any sugestions please?

Thank you!
Filip

Comment: You'll need to check your error log for the specific error that might have caused this. A 500 "internal Server Error" is just a general error response - an unexpected error condition. A common cause is syntax errors in .htaccess files - although if that was the case you probably wouldn't be able to do anything?

Comment: There is also the Joomla Stack Exchange site where this might be better suited: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/